# Performance varies dramatically if a function is moved between modules

Tags: haskell, compiler-optimization

If I move a function from where it's used into a separate module, I've noticed the performance of the program drops significantly.

```
calc = sum . nub . map third . filter isProd . concat . map parts . permutations
    where third (_,_,b)          = fromDigits b
          isProd (a,b,p)         = fromDigits a * fromDigits b == fromDigits p
          -- All possibilities have digits: A x AAAA or AA x AAA
          parts (a:b:c:d:e:rest) = [([a], [b,c,d,e], rest)
                                   ,([a,b], [c,d,e], rest)]
```

in another module:

```
fromDigits :: Integral a => [a] -> a                                   
fromDigits = foldl1' (\a b -> 10 * a + b)
```

This runs in 0.1 seconds when `fromDigits` is in the same module, but 0.4 seconds when I move it to another module.

I assume this is because GHC can't inline the function if it's in different module, but I feel like it *should* be able to, since they are in the same package.

I'm not sure what the compiler settings are, but it's built with Leksah/cabal defaults. I'm fairly sure that's with -O2 as a minimum.

Comment: GHC can inline across modules. See this for some tips: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/GHC#Modules_and_separate_compilation

Comment: You could try adding a `{-# INLINE fromDigits #-}`-annotation near the `fromDigits` definition...

Comment: Thanks, the INLINE pragma works. But.. it feels a bit strange not to be able to specify that at the call site.

Comment: I looked at the performance tips wiki page, but I couldn't find any example usage for the compiler args. Can I specify the thresholds as a pragma too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the type-class polymorphic `fromDigits`, you get a function that is, due to the dictionary lookups for `(+)`, `(*)` and `fromInteger`, too large to have its unfolding automatically exposed. That means it can't be specialised at the call sites and the dictionary lookups can't be eliminated to possibly inline addition and multiplication (which might enable further optimisation).

When it is defined in the same module as it is used in, with optimisations, GHC creates a specialised version for the type it's used at, if that is known. Then the dictionary lookups can be eliminated and the `(+)` and `(*)` operations can be inlined (if the type they're used at has operations suitable for inlining).

But that depends on the type being known. So if you have the polymorphic `calc` and `fromDigits` in one module, but use it only in some other module, you are again in the position that only the generic version is available, but since its unfolding is not exposed, it can't be specialised or otherwise optimised at the call site.

One solution is to make the unfolding of the function exposed in the interface file, so it can be properly optimised where it is used, when the necessary data (in particular the type) is available. You can expose the function's unfolding in the interface file by adding an `{-# INLINE #-}`, or, as of GHC 7, an `{-# INLINABLE #-}` pragma to the function. That makes the almost unchanged source code available when compiling the calling code, so the function can be properly optimised with more information available.

The downside to this is code-bloat, you get a copy of the optimised code at every call site (for `INLINABLE` it's not so extreme, you get at least one copy per calling module, that's usually not too bad).

An alternative solution is to generate specialised versions in the defining module by adding `{-# SPECIALISE #-}` pragmas (US spelling also accepted) to let GHC create optimised versions for the important types (`Int`, `Integer`, `Word`, ?). That also creates rewrite rules, so that uses at the specialised-for types get rewritten to use the specialised version (when compiling with optimisations).

The downside to this is that some optimisations that would be possible when the code is inlined aren't.

Comment: My understanding is that with `{-# INLINABLE #-}`, you can get sharing of specializations, so it's not quite so bad as a copy at every call site.

Comment: True. Added that as an afterthought, forgot to update the code-bloat remark. Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 5):

You can tell GHC to inline a function at the call site using the `inline` function: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/GHC-Prim.html#v%3Ainline. You may want to use it in conjunction with the `INLINABLE` pragma: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#inlinable-pragma